# Error in determining frequency of a string in a string array

Tags: java, string, frequency

For a code as given below:

```
    String array = "AB AB AB AB";
    String[] part = array.split(" ");
    int cc = Collections.frequency(Arrays.asList(array), part[0]);
    System.out.println("Count: " + cc);
```

I am getting an output:

```
0
```

whereas, the desired output is:

```
4
```

Comment: You made a typo: it should be `Arrays.asList(part)` and not `Arrays.asList(array)`.

Comment: Questions about a problem that ***can no longer be reproduced or that was caused by a simple typographical error***. While similar questions may be on-topic here, these are often resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the [shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting.

Comment: Please close/delete this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you have `int cc = Collections.frequency(Arrays.asList(array), part[0]);` .

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String array = "AB AB AB AB";
        String[] part = array.split(" ");
        int cc = Collections.frequency(Arrays.asList(part), part[0]);
        System.out.println("Count: " + cc);

    }

}
```

Comment: Yes this should be close voted instead of being answered to.

Comment: `// TODO Auto-generated method stub`? Seriously?

Comment: @Tunaki : Eclipse generated method so //TODO

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo probably, in the following line, change array to part.

```
int cc = Collections.frequency(Arrays.asList(part), part[0]);
```

Arrays.asList(array) gives you a list like {"AB AB AB AB"}

Arrays.asList(part) gives you a list like {"AB", "AB", "AB", "AB"}, which is what you really want.

Comment: A typo should be close voted instead of being answered to please.